# Implementing a proxy (both client part and server part) in C (with socket programming)

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, segmentation-fault

I am currently working on a Proxy that should get the browser's request, forward it to the server and then return the server's reply so that the requested page can download.The proxy should support both HTTP 1.0 and 1.1.

I have to write this program in C, with socket programming, but I am new in both (I have only ever programmed in Ada). So I tried to write something, but as soon as I run my program and try to connect, I get a "Segmentation fault" error and I don't know what it could mean. I've read that it was about pointers/strings and memory, but I don't know why I'm getting these errors.

here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write
#include<netdb.h> //hostent


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket ;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char message_from_browser[2000];
    int len;

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("bind failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
int c;
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
{
    puts("Connection accepted");

if (new_socket<0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
}

close(socket_desc); // don't need this anymore

puts("okay dude??");

if (recv(new_socket, message_from_browser, 2000, 0)<=0)
    {
    puts("error: connection");
    }

    puts(message_from_browser);

    puts ("Request Received!");

puts("okay huhhh??");

// oKAY i receive the request! Now extract the hostname from the request!

char my_hostname[256];
int j=0;

puts("we created j so");

// doesn't workkkkk: Segmentation error

while (j < strcspn(strstr(message_from_browser, "www."), "/"))
        {
            my_hostname[j] = strstr(message_from_browser, "www.")[j];
            j++;
            puts(j);
        }

        puts("hostname found! It is: \r");
        puts(my_hostname);

        char *hostname = my_hostname;
        char ip[100];
        struct hostent *he;
        struct in_addr **addr_list;
        int i;

if ( (he = gethostbyname( hostname ) ) == NULL)
{
    //gethostbyname failed
    herror("gethostbyname");
    return 1;
}

//Cast the h_addr_list to in_addr , since h_addr_list also has the ip address in long format only
addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;

for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    //Return the first one;
    strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
}

  printf("we now have the ip we want to connect to and it is: %s \n", ip);

  // CLIENT SIDE

    struct sockaddr_in actual_server;
    char server_reply[2000];
    int socket_client;

    socket_client = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    if (socket_client <0 )
        {
            puts("error: couldn't create socket");
        }



// remove the "http" from the message of the browser
    /*char message_from_browser_edited[2000];
    char token_1[1993];
    char token_2[4];
    int k=0;
    int l=0;
    int m=0;

    while (k < strcspn(message_from_browser, "http"))
        {
            token_1[k] = message_from_browser[k];
            k++;
        }

    while (l < 1992)
        {
            my_hostname[l] = strstr(message_from_browser, "http")[l];
            l++;
        }

    for (m=0; m<=1992; m++)
    {
        if (m<=3)
        message_from_browser_edited[m] = token_1[m] ;
        else
        message_from_browser_edited[m] = token_2[m-4];
    }
puts("We edited the browser's message");

puts(message_from_browser_edited);*/

// now we have the true message from the browser

    if (write(socket_client, message_from_browser, 2000 )<0)
    {
        puts("error: wouldn't write :(");
    }
    puts("written!");
 // client reaching actual server

    actual_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip); // ip is the result of gethostbyname
    actual_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    actual_server.sin_port = htons( 80 ); // it's 80 bc the client side of the proxy is now trying to access the actual internet

    if (connect(socket_client , (struct sockaddr *)&actual_server , sizeof(actual_server)) < 0)
        {
            puts("connect error");
            return 1;
        }
    puts("Connected!!!");

    if( send(socket_client , message_from_browser, 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed   :( ");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send!!!!");

//Receive a reply from the server
    if( recv(socket_client, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }
    puts("Reply received\n");
    puts(server_reply);
    puts("     ");


    // BACK TO THE SERVER SIDE that will send the message back to the browser.

        if (send(new_socket, server_reply, 2000, 0) == -1)
        {
        perror("send");
        close(new_socket);
        exit(0);
        }

    close(new_socket);  // parent doesn't need this

} // this is for the while

return 0;

} // this is the main
```

I've scattered a few messages here and there to pinpoint where exactly the problem is and I found out that it's where I try to extract the host name from the browser's request (I put a comment here that says I got a Segmentation Error). This is weird because it used to work before I made other changes, so I put the changes in comments in hope that it would work again but it doesn't... So I really don't understand what could be wrong. I know that the error is in the while loop's statements but I don't know what's wrong with what I wrote ((j < strcspn(strstr(message_from_browser, "www."), "/"))). Is there any way to fix that issue? And am I even doing the right thing for the proxy to work?

Thank you!

Comment: First thing: Learn how to use a debugger. 2nd: Learn how C-"string"s work. They are differnet.

Comment: Final: Always compile with all warning on, take them serious and fix your code until now more warnings are issued by the compiler.